# How to use an implicit Intent to give choices to perform a certain action?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-implicit-intent

Like getting an image. I want to give users the choice to access either the camera, gallery or any other app which can return an image.

Comment: follow this link :-> http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-1

Answer (score 0):

Create dialog with three options camera, gallery, file explorer.

When user select an option from the dialog call  proper intent to open selected application.

Please refer the link :http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

Hope this will help you

Comment: I have tried that @EKN , i was looking for a way to access the in-built apps without custom creating a dialog for giving the choice. Is there any other way...i cannot wrap my head around this problem because of me being new to android.